# How to create an associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need an array to be created in the following format :

```
{"3":
    {"label":"All i want for christmas",
     "song":"Alliw_1405399165.mp3",
     "name":"All i want for christmas"},
"4":
    {"label":"Call your girlfriend robyn clip",
     "song":"Gangnam_Style_2.m4a",
     "name":"Call your girlfriend robyn},
"5":
    {"label":"Gangnam style psy clip",
     "song":"Samba_De_Janeiro-world_cup_for_jivebird.m4a",
     "name":"Gangnam style psy clip"} }
```

I  am filling these values after an ajax response in the following manner :

```
$.each(response.result, function(i,item){

                        label = item.name;
                        if((item.special_price < item.price)&&(item.special_price!=0) && (item.special_price!=null)) {
                            label += '- is Only '+ item.special_price + item.currencysymbol;
                        }

                        tmpsongList[item.product_id].push({'label': label,
                                                    'song': item.audiofile,
                                                    'name': item.name,
                                                    'tag': item.tag,
                                                    'song_path': item.audio_url});

                });
```

But this cause the following error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

How can i create an array like this.Please help me to solve this
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a method on arrays (*not* plain objects) that puts the value you pass to it onto the end of the array.

You aren't trying to put a value on the end of the object, you are trying to assign it to a specific index.

```
tmpsongList[item.product_id] = { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

its not an array, its a map/object.
var a = {} is an object/map.
var a = [] is an array.
in your case, you need to

```
tmpsongList[item.product_id] = {'label': label,
                                                'song': item.audiofile,
                                                'name': item.name,
                                                'tag': item.tag,
                                                'song_path': item.audio_url};
```